# Android: Can't change properties of MenuItem in OnCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

It's very simple. I have following code:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(isReturn) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_returned, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        } else {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_return, menu);
            MenuItem red = menu.findItem(R.id.action_error);
            red.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_error_red);
//            if (sellStatus.equals(Bill.ERROR_CREATE)) {
//                red.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_error_red);
//            } else if (sellStatus.equals(Bill.ERROR_DATABASE)) {
//                red.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_error_orange);
//            } else{
//                red.setVisible(false);
//            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

XML menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_return"
        android:title="Return"
        app:showAsAction="withText|always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_error"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I'm trying to change MenuItem's properties(setIcon, setVisible). But it don't change MenutItem properties(I guess , It can't connect MenuItem).

But it's taking onOptionsItemSelected and icons from xml. 
Is it android bug or am i missing some pattern?

Comment: probably your `isReturn` is always true?

Comment: no, isReturn works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your menu appearance in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`. This allow you to change the menu appearance azccording to the state of your app.